# Monitor Node-red flows Execution

Tags: node-red

I am a newbie to node-red and working on some of the node red flows which involves connecting and processing data from MQTT, MongoDB etc. Is there any reporting page that displays information about flow executions and their related logs?

Answer (score 1):

Not really.

The best you could possibly do is ensure that all debug nodes are set to write to the the console as well as the sidebar, then tail the Node-RED log.

Nodes should log errors (such as MQTT/MongoDB disconnect/reconnect) to the log as well or you can use the status node and wire that to a debug node in order to capture the state changes that way as well. (Note as thrashed out in the comments, status nodes messages do not have payload key, so make sure you set the debug node properly)

Comment: I have used the status nodes followed by debug node which shows the status as undefined in case of any settings change for MQTT subscriber

Comment: Have you set the debug node to show the whole message not just `msg.payload`?

Comment: It was msg.payload. I have not used whole message object

Comment: Please note the comment in the info bar for the status node > "This node does not produce a payload.". Change the debug node to show the whole message and you will see the output